# Getting repo code from BitBucket using API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

We have a requirement to get repo code using the Bitbucket API.

I am able to list all the api for a user, using basic auth, but while using the

"https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D"

, it gives a 404 error where I am passing the uuid of repo as the repo slug.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Can you not just use the raw download URLs?

Comment: Need the access token for the download, cannot move ahead with the bare code.